# What does the "L" in inductance stand for?

Tags: inductor, inductance

"R" is resistor/resistance, and "C" is capacitor/capacitance, that makes sense. But where comes the "L" for inductor/inductance come from?

*edit*: Wikipedia says it's **possibly** in honor of Heinrich Lenz, but I'd like to hear something more affirmative.

Comment: My guess is that I was taken (current), so that's what happened. There are more quantities than English letters, which causes these problems - some of them don't make sense. (Conductance - G, Reactance - X, Admittance - Y, Impedance - Z, Susceptance - B, etc.) Edit: Actually, impedance perhaps does make sense, as Z is often used for complex numbers.

Comment: Not an answer... but somewhere i heard that, L is used for coil because Coil and Capacitor both start with C, so to abbreviate **Coil-Capacitor circuit**, use of of same letter would be confusing. so it is written **LC** , where L is the last letter of coiL.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As exscape already mentioned, the symbol I was already taken for current (Ampère referred to electric current as "l'intensité du courant électrique", and used the symbol I in his equations).

According to a [bio for Heinrich Lenz](https://nationalmaglab.org/education/magnet-academy/history-of-electricity-magnetism/pioneers/heinrich-friedrich-emil-lenz) on the website of the National High Magnetic Field Laboratory (which is affiliated with the Los Alamos National Laboratory),

> Lenz’s name, or at least his first initial, is attached to still one
>   more area of physics nomenclature. The symbol “L” was chosen to
>   represent “inductance” in honor of his pioneering work in
>   electromagnetism.